# How to call the AsyncTask in the fragment from other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

How to call the AsyncTask in the fragment from other fragment ?

The code of the `AsyncTask` in the Fragment.

```
public class FileBrowserFragment extends Fragment {

    private class ContiunedDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<FileBrowser, Integer, FileBrowser> {

                @Override
                protected FileBrowser doInBackground(FileBrowser... browsers) {

                    browsers[0].retrieveFileList(mDirectory, FileNode.Format.all, false) ;
                    return browsers[0] ;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(FileBrowser result) {

                    Activity activity = getActivity() ;
                    if (activity == null)
                        return ;

                    if (activity != null) {


                    List<FileNode> fileList = result.getFileList() ;

                    mFileList.addAll(fileList) ;

                    mFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ;

                    if (!result.isCompleted() && fileList.size() != 0) {
                        mFileListTitle.setText(mFileBrowser + " : " + mReading + " " + mDirectory + " ("
                                + mFileList.size() + " " + mItems +")") ;

                        Log.i(TAG, "mFileListTitle-----11111 = " + mFileListTitle.getText());

                        new ContiunedDownloadTask().execute(result) ;
                    } else {
                        mFileListTitle.setText(mFileBrowser + " : " + mDirectory + " (" + mFileList.size()
                                + " " + mItems +")") ;

                        Log.i(TAG, "mFileListTitle-----22222 = " + mFileListTitle.getText());
                        setWaitingState(false) ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How to call the `AsyncTask` in the `FileBrowserFragment` in the other `fragment` ?

Comment: Why do you need this? Create a class for that asynctask and make objects of it and call anytime you need.If you don't want to do this, than change it's access modifier to public

Comment: move asynctask to a separate .java file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your asynctask in its own file. To do that create another java file named ContiunedDownloadTask.java and copy your class in it. Then you can call the method below:

```
new ContiunedDownloadTask().execute(fileBrowser);
```

If you really want to keep the class definition in fragment's class, then you need to make it public static and call it like this:

```
new FileBrowserFragment.ContiunedDownloadTask().execute(fileBrowser);
```

Comment: So...if I don't do that , I can not call the AsyncTask in fragment from the other fragment ?

Comment: You can, but you need to make it a public class. And when you make it public, there's no reason to keep the class definition in fragment's class.

Comment: I have change the AsyncTask from private to public , and I just want to know how to call AsyncTask from the other Fragment. Please teach me how to do ? thanks !!

Comment: I forgot to mention static in my previous comment, you need to make it public static. I edited my answer accordingly.